# aspx button click with https issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, https

I am using visual studio 2010 with framework 4.

I have an aspx page that has  some fields for a user to enter search criteria with and a `GridView` that is initiall empty.  Once the user enters the fields they want to search by, they click a button.  The click event then fires and retrieves the data and fills the GridView.

I have deployed the application to our server and it works great with http.  However, when we switch to https, the page is displayed but when the search button is clicked, it returns with a 404 error.

We had some early errors on the http that were due to firewall limitations but the network guy says he is not seeing errors this time.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you have a hard-coded URL somewhere in your application. Search for http:// and you should be able to track it down.

Alternatively, install [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com) and see what URL is trying to be accessed when the 404 error is encountered, then track down that URL in your code.

Comment: Didn't mean to press enter.    Fiddler shows the exact same URL for the button click as it did for the initial page load.